# How to reduce netty garbage production?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, netty

I have network application that handles about 40k msg/sec written using netty framework and I  want to reduce the number of garbage collector calls. While profiling I found that there is significant amount of `byte[]` instances and I suspect that it comes from this part of code :

```java
public class MessageHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) {

    ChannelBuffer message = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
}

}
```

Is it possible to force netty to reuse/pool `ChannelBuffers` somehow to prevent it to construct them every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We plan to implement pooling of buffers, but its not done yet.

See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/62

Comment: So netty creates new ChannelBuffer every time, when the new message arrives?

Comment: Is there a simple way I can avoid this? I have only a tcp client and don't want to produce another garbage, by allocating a bunch of ChannelBuffers. Maybe I can fork netty and change a bit, but I am quiet new to this library.

Comment: I think there is no easy way atm. But I'm working on it. Not sure when it will get finished, As it depend on my free time..

Comment: In the general case object pooling doesn't work very well in Java.  The lock overhead alone makes it challenging to get right, and the pooled objects become something akin to zombies - they screw up the young/old object relationship.  General advice from the JVM guys is:  please don't do this.    That said, this particular object doesn't seem to have any children other than an array of primitives, so it might work.  But I don't know how helpful it'll actually be.

Comment: @shg I think its one of the next things that we will finish and it will be definitly be part of netty 4.0.0.Final once it is out

Comment: Implemented in Dec 2012.